# R: How to read a file into a data table with different splits?

Tags: r

I have a data file that looks like this:

```
ABC 123456789
DEF 987654321
GHI 123456789
```

I want to put this in a data table (in R) in this way:

```
ABC 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
DEF 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
GHI 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

So, the `ABC` together in one column, and the `numbers` each apart in separate columns.

I know how to split the data, and of course the numbers must be split by `''`.  But I don't know how to use this in this case, because I don't want to split the entire file by `''`; only the second 'column', with the numbers.

Could anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read in the original file and then use `strsplit` on the second column to generate the columns you want:

```
df <- data.frame(v1=c("ABC", "DEF"),
                 v2=c("1234", "5678"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df <- data.frame(cbind(df$v1, t(apply(df, 1, function(x) strsplit(x[2], "", fixed=TRUE)[[1]]))))
df

   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1 ABC  1  2  3  4
2 DEF  5  6  7  8
```

This assumes that your input file looked like:

```
ABC 1234
DEF 5678
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use some regular expressions and `read.table` as follows. One can also use `read.csv`. The point is to introduce a comma  separator and then use that to read in the data. See notes below:

```
res <- read.table(text=gsub("([0-9])()","\\1,","ABC 123456789
 DEF 987654321
 GHI 123456789"), sep = ",")[-10]
 library(dplyr) # Just the pipe
 res %>% 
   tidyr::separate(V1,c("ROW","FIRST"))
  ROW FIRST V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
1 ABC     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
2 DEF     9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
3 GHI     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

**Note**

1. We can do without the `separate` by using a much more general regex in our `gsub`.
2. We can also manually remove the unwanted column(s) after the reading hence removing the `[-10]` used above. It is possible that one may not know  the length in which case `str` might be useful.